# Simple destructuring extractor for command line args

Tags: scala

The preferred approach would be to use something similar to the commented out line below.

```
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
//    val (dbPropsFile, tsvFile, dbTable) = args
    val dbPropsFile = args(0)
    val tsvFile = args(1)
    val dbTable = args(2)
```

However I am having a little quarrel with the compiler over it:

```
Error:(13, 9) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : (T1, T2, T3)
 required: Array[String]
    val (dbPropsFile, tsvFile, dbTable) = args

    ^
```

So all told this should be an easy few points for someone out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use 
   `val Array(dbPropsFile, tsvFile, dbTable) = args`

```
scala> val Array(a,b,c) = Array(1,2,3)
a: Int = 1
b: Int = 2
c: Int = 3

scala> a
res0: Int = 1
```

Comment: If interested in first three items only, val Array(a,b,c, _*) = Array(1,2,3,4,5,6)